# String is equal to an If statement value and yet doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, if-statement, swift2

I have problem with the following code:

```
            if finalName == "London, GB" {

        let londonImage = UIImage(named: "united-kingdom-1043062.jpg")

        imageViewPage1.image = londonImage

    }

    if finalName == "Novaya Gollandiya, RU" {

        let StPetersbourgImage = UIImage(named: "architecture-995613_1920.jpg")

        imageViewPage1.image = StPetersbourgImage

    }

    if finalName == "Berlin, DE" {

        let BerlinImage = UIImage(named: "siegessaule-200714_1920.jpg")

        imageViewPage1.image = BerlinImage

    }

    if finalName == "Tel Aviv, IL" {

        let TelAvivImage = UIImage(named: "buildings-89111.jpg")

        imageViewPage1.image = TelAvivImage

    }

    else {

        let elseImage = UIImage(named: "sun-203792.jpg")

        imageViewPage1.image = elseImage

    }

}
```

I already debugged and the value is "Berlin, DE" and it still does the else instead of the finalName == "Berlin, DE".

Comment: Don't replace your question with the answer! Questions are for questions, and answers are for answers... pretty straightforward, actually. If an existing answer solved your issue, mark the answer as accepted, otherwise post your own *answer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use if else if.

```
if finalName == "London, GB" {
     let londonImage = UIImage(named: "united-kingdom-1043062.jpg")
     imageViewPage1.image = londonImage
}
else if finalName == "Novaya Gollandiya, RU" {
     let StPetersbourgImage = UIImage(named: "architecture-995613_1920.jpg")
     imageViewPage1.image = StPetersbourgImage
}
else if finalName == "Berlin, DE" {
     let BerlinImage = UIImage(named: "siegessaule-200714_1920.jpg")
     imageViewPage1.image = BerlinImage
}
else if finalName == "Tel Aviv, IL" {
     let TelAvivImage = UIImage(named: "buildings-89111.jpg")
     imageViewPage1.image = TelAvivImage
}
else {
     let elseImage = UIImage(named: "sun-203792.jpg")
     imageViewPage1.image = elseImage
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html

Have a look again at the options.

In your code, each `if() {...}` has no else conditions except the last one for Tel Aviv.  Even if the Berlin match was made and the values set, the else would then fire when comparing against Tel Aviv (because the string can't be both Berlin and Tel Aviv at the same time) and overwrote the values with something else.

What you probably wanted to do in this case to make it work, is use `else if` for all the `if`'s except the first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `else` statement.

Because you are checking for 
`if finalName == "Tel Aviv, IL"`
and the value is not `Tel Aviv, IL`, it executes the `else` statement.

You should rewrite your `if` conditions into `else if` style or better convert it to `switch`.